# Determining Encoding in MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access, unicode, encoding

I have a MS Access database with a column that has some strange encoding. Oddly, I am unable to copy/paste this into anything (Chrome, Word, etc), because it strips out most of the unicode characters (though not all of them). What I am wondering, is there a way to determine what type of encoding is being used here?

[image: Image of the encoding]

Somehow the program I am using is taking this column and decoding it to readable text. I converted the Access database to PostgreSQL on a Linux system, but I'm pretty sure whatever encoding is being used here did not map correctly into the PostgreSQL database. What I'm trying to do is to convert this to hex, but I cannot do it since I'm unable to copy/paste the characters out of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the table as a recordset. Then loop the records and convert the field to hex using a function like this:

```
Public Function StrToByte(ByVal strChars As String) As String

  Dim abytChar()  As Byte
  Dim lngChar     As Long
  Dim strByte     As String

  abytChar() = StrConv(strChars, vbFromUnicode)

  strByte = Space(2 * (1 + UBound(abytChar) - LBound(abytChar)))
  For lngChar = LBound(abytChar) To UBound(abytChar)
    Mid(strByte, 1 + 2 * lngChar) = Hex(abytChar(lngChar))
  Next

  StrToByte = strByte

End Function
```

Or create a query:

```
Select *, StrToByte([EncryptedFieldName]) As HexField
From tblYourTable
```